# How to return image in NodeJS after intercepted image get request?

Tags: node.js, express, requestjs

I am trying to intercept requests for html elements (like images and scripts) that is referenced with relative path from my website and retrieve them from a 2nd website using [requestJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) for NodeJS , this works with scripts but I can’t figure a way to retrieve images.
For example in my home page .html (127.0.0.1:3030) I have:

```
<script src="/main/mainscript.js"></script>
```

Intercepted to retrieve "http://my2website.com/main/mainscript.js", works fine

```
<img src=”/images/logo.png”/>
```

Intercepted to retrieve "http://my2website.com/images/logo.png", but I always get error even if I can see that the response headers attributes matches the required file.

Using this code :

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  var options = {
    url: 'http://my2website.com'+ req.path,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': req.headers['user-agent']
    }
  };
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        res.send(body);
    }
    else {
        console.log('request error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
});
```

Please forgive my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `encoding: null` in your `options`. This will keep binary data intact by keeping the response as a `Buffer` instance instead of converting it to a UTF-8 string:

```
  var options = {
    url: 'http://my2website.com'+ req.path,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': req.headers['user-agent']
    },
    encoding: null
  };
```